# Only complete command names if no file name completions exist

Tags: command-line, zsh

Reasoning:
I have autocd enabled, yet I never use it because it makes tab-completion a huge pain, as every single command name on my system will be completed along with the filename completions.

Desired behavior:
I want zsh to ONLY tab-complete commands if the completed string is not a prefix of any of the files in the current folder.

Example of desired behavior:

```
$ ls
foo1
foo2
$f<TAB>
foo1
foo2
$fi<TAB>
find
... (other commands that start with fi)
```

I guess if this is not possible it would at least be nice to put directory completions before command completions.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following three lines in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
zle -C complete-files complete-word _generic
zstyle ':completion:complete-files:*' completer _files
bindkey "^F" complete-files
```

this binds `Ctrl-f` to file/folder completion, so if I know I definitely want to tab complete a filename then I use `Ctrl-f` instead of `<tab>`. Obviously you can use a different binding by changing `^F` to something else. The result:

```
$ ls
  foo1
  foo2
$ f<tab>
  f2py
  factor
  faillog
  ...
$ f<Ctrl-f>
  foo1
  foo2
```

Comment: I was aware you can do this but this requires me to think what kind of tab completion I want before I tab-complete which is a big no-no for me.

Answer (score 2):

To get this exact behavior put this to your .zshrc:

```
compdef '_autocd || _command_names' -command-
```

I found the answer in [this thread](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2013/msg00129.html).

Answer (score 0):

On bash if you do

```
. f<TAB>
```

then only file names will be listed. I don't know if zsh have the same behaviour. In general, bash autocompletes using only file names when you must input a path.